# Accessing/modifying array in perl

Tags: perl

Is there any way that when we push an element to an array, can we push it to specific columns.

Im trying to do something like this.

```
push (@array, $val ); .......$val should always go to first column.
push (@array, $val2); .......$val2 should go to second column
push (@array, $val3);........$val3 should go to third
```

I tried giving \t but didnt get right results.

```
elsif ($line =~/RELATION/){
push (@mystuff, "$line" .",");
$line = &getline;
}
```

My sample txt file looks like this

```
SEVERITY Warning
NODE OTHER "awssystem"
APPLICATION "AWS"
MSGGRP "OpC"
OBJECT "Audit"
MSGKEY "<$MSG_NODE>:hello"
ACK  "<$MSG_NODE>:hello"
TEXT "Test one two three"
AUTOACTION "echo \"It has to ack after AA\" > /tmp/banack" ACTIONNODE IP 0.0.0.0  "<$OPC_MGMTSV>" ANNOTATE ACK
                      OPACTION "echo `hostname`" ANNOTATE
                      TROUBLETICKET
                      HELPTEXT "Hello what is this"

SEVERITY Warning
NODE OTHER "awssystem"
MSGGRP "OpC"
OBJECT "Audit"
MSGKEY "<$MSG_NODE>:hello"
MSGKEYRELATION ACK  "<$MSG_NODE>:hello"
```

I have many similar entries like this in my text file. I'm trying to capture only Severity, application, msggrp and object, in the above output application is missing so i just need to put a whitepace if it can't find an application.

My code looks like this:

```
while ($#myarr > 0 )
-------
---
elsif ($line =~/SEVERITY/){
push (@mystuff, "$line" .",");
$line = &getline;
}
```

I want my ouput shld look line this

```
SEVERITY Warning APPLICATION "AWS" MSGGRP "OpC"
SEVERITY Warning                   MSGGRP "OpC"
```

But my output looks like this

```
SEVERITY Warning APPLICATION "AWS" MSGGRP "OpC"
SEVERITY Warning MSGGRP "OpC"
```

Comment: Could you explain what output you want?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %res;
my @res;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/(SEVERITY)/) {
        push @res,{%res} if $.>1;
        %res = map{$_ => ''}qw/APPLICATION MSGGRP/;
        $res{$1} = $_;
    } elsif (/(APPLICATION|MSGGRP)/) {
        $res{$1} = $_;
    }
}
push @res,{%res};

foreach my $res(@res) {
format STDOUT = 
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$res->{SEVERITY}, $res->{APPLICATION}, $res->{MSGGRP}
.
write;
}

__DATA__
SEVERITY Warning
NODE OTHER "awssystem"
APPLICATION "AWS"
MSGGRP "OpC"
OBJECT "Audit"
MSGKEY "<$MSG_NODE>:hello"
ACK  "<$MSG_NODE>:hello"
TEXT "Test one two three"
AUTOACTION "echo \"It has to ack after AA\" > /tmp/banack" ACTIONNODE IP 0.0.0.0  "<$OPC_MGMTSV>" ANNOTATE ACK
                      OPACTION "echo `hostname`" ANNOTATE
                      TROUBLETICKET
                      HELPTEXT "Hello what is this"

SEVERITY Warning
NODE OTHER "awssystem"
MSGGRP "OpC"
OBJECT "Audit"
MSGKEY "<$MSG_NODE>:hello"
MSGKEYRELATION ACK  "<$MSG_NODE>:hello"
```

**output:**

```
SEVERITY Warning      APPLICATION "AWS"     MSGGRP "OpC"
SEVERITY Warning                            MSGGRP "OpC"
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "push to column"?

You can store the value at a certain position in an array

```
$array[0] = $val ;  # $val is 1. element
$array[1] = $val2 ; # $val2 is 2. element
$array[2] = $val3 ; # ...
```

This is the same as

```
push @array , $val , $val2 , $val3 ;
```

assuming the `@array` was empty before.

Comment: sorry i should have been more specific.My txt file looks like somthing  like this

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

`push(@array, $val, $val2, $val3)`